# How to calculate the perimeter of a polygon with n sides using chords.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

This question comes from the first problem set of the MIT OCW calc course. It asks for the formula of the perimeter of a regular polygon with *n* sides with a radius of 1. The answer sheet has this for the answer

$$n\sin(2\pi/n)$$

If each wedge of the polygon creates a chord length of $2\sin(\theta/2)$ (the half-angle formula) and each wedge is $2\pi/n$ radians why is the answer not $2n\sin(\pi/n)$? I get the $(\pi/n)$ by multiplying $2\pi/n$ by $1/2$.

I know I must be missing something, but I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: You need to specify that the circumradius is $1$, or the problem doesn't make sense.  As to the answer, you're right.  It must be a typo on the answer sheet.  You can easily check by setting n=4$.

Comment: you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming regular polygon,

$$ AB=u = R \cdot \sin \dfrac{\pi}{n} $$

perimeter

$$ 2u n = 2nR \sin \dfrac{\pi}{n} $$

when $n\to \infty $ perimeter $\to 2 \pi R$

Take $R=1$ here if so desired in this example.

It may be a typo error in the student's answer sheet.

Here the polygon drawn is for $n=8$ sides.

[image]